# Image Is Not Populating When Inserting Image Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

When I try to load a UIImageView with an image (either a specific image or an image from an array), my UIImageView just shows blank with running the app; no image at all. I'm not getting any syntax errors. Below you'll see that I tried two different assignments, one direct and one using an array, and neither worked. The NSLog confirms that a number is being stored in my imageDisplay variable. Any ideas? What am I missing?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     KanaCharacters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"i.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"u.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"o.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ka.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ki.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ku.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ke.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ko.png"],
                  nil];

int imageDisplay = arc4random_uniform([KanaCharacters count]);
NSLog(@"%d", imageDisplay);    //3


Monster1.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)([UIImage    
imageWithContentsOfFile:@"e.png"])];

 //    Monster1 = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(49, 49, 45, 45))] 
 initWithImage:[KanaCharacters objectAtIndex:imageDisplay]];
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `Monster1` is not `nil`? Has it been added to its parent view?

Comment: And why not just do `Monster1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"];`? Why do all of the "CGImage" stuff? And `imageWithContentsOfFile:` requires a full path to the image.

Comment: @Rmaddy I'm actually hoping to populate it from the array, the direct ping was just to see if I could get the image to populate at all.

Comment: @David I don't believe I'm using ARC. How could I check?

Comment: Show the actual code you are using when trying to use the image from the array. The commented code in your question creates a new image view that is never added to the main view.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it made a new image view. I'm just trying to populate a UIImageView I have created on the storyboard with an image programmatically, and I just cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe it was this simple, but here it is:

```
[Monster1 setImage:[KanaCharacters objectAtIndex:imageDisplay]];
```

All it needed was brackets.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `Monster1` image to come from the array `kanaCharacters` with the index number from `imageDisplay` wouldn't you do this?

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil]; //Setup array

int imageDisplay = arc4random_uniform([array count]); //Find random int from array count

UIImageView *monster1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)]; //Setup UIImageView

monster1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:array[imageDisplay]]; //Display image which is randomly selected from array

[self.view addSubview:monster1]; //Add image to view
```

Comment: Monster1.image line returns an exception error that an unrecognized selector is being sent to the instance. It seems like it's passing the int value of imageDisplay instead of the array object found at the index of imageDisplay.

Comment: @Michelle sorry my mistake the array was creating UIImages Not the string names for the images, code has been fixed and should work.